# Menu strip access from other Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to deactivate my menu strip or my sub menu strip from `form2` or `form3`

The problem is that the menu strip is private. I cannot access it from the other form where I can change the value. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Create a public property in `Form1` and create a getter and setter that exposed those menu strips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to access a private control of a form from the outside and don't make your menu `public` - it's not the right solution to your problem. If you make your controls public, you allow other components to access those controls without a chance to intervene - outside callers can make changes to the form's state without the form being aware of it. This may work in very small programs but it leads to code that's impossible to maintain as it grows because the various UI elements start depending on each other: as you change one, you'll have to update the code in other components to keep things building without errors. It's very hard to do this without breaking functionality.

If you need to affect one form from another, the correct way to do it is to acquire a temporary reference to the target form (preferably just an interface) and then to tell the target form to deactivate its own menu.

This keeps the menu a private component (as it should be) but still gives you the ability to tell the target form to update the status of the menu.

For example:

```
// Form1.Designer.cs
partial class Form1
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip1;

    // ...
}

// Form with menu
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void UpdateMenuStatus ( bool bEnable )
    {
        // update menu status here
    }
}

// Form that wants to update the menu on Form1
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void SomeFunc ()
    {
        Form1 form1 = GetForm1Reference ();

        form1.UpdateMenuStatus ( true );
    }
}
```

The function `GetForm1Reference ()` should look up the requested `Form1` reference in a global list/map that you maintain - this way you don't hardcode a particular instance of your form within other forms - you want to keep these different forms as separate from each other as possible so that changing one doesn't force you to change the others.